# Press enter in textbox when editing ListView causes exception (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, listview

I used standard drag and drop to put in a ASP ListView with editing enabled. The table is two columns, a GUID primary key, and a text string name. Null is not allowed for either.

When I edit a record (for the name column), I change its value (to a valid value) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it crashes with a Cannot insert NULL into column named "Name". However, if I do exactly the same, but instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> I click update, it works fine.

I am new to ASP.NET. What am I missing?

Comment: What underlying data source object are you using ?
ObjectDataSource / SqlDataSoure or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is triggering the default button on the page, probably not your update button.

Use tab to see the focus moving around the page, hit tab then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back, see where the focus is.  Pressing that button/link should yield the same result with the null error, what's that button/link doing?